# Удалить все четные числа из файла

Tags: python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

Дан текстовый файл содержащий целые числа.
Необходимо удалить из него все четные числа
Текст в файле:

> Определение целых чисел утверждает, что любое из чисел 1, 2, 3, 4,
>   число 0, а также любое из чисел 671, 256, 35  является целым. Теперь
>   мы легко можем привести примеры целых чисел. Например, число 38 –
>   целое, число 70040 – тоже целое, нуль – целое число (напомним, что
>   нуль НЕ является натуральным числом, нуль – целое число), числа 999,
>   1, 8, 93, 832, – также являются примерами целых чисел. Все целые числа
>   удобно представлять как последовательность целых чисел, которая имеет
>   следующий вид: 0, 1, 2, 3, … Последовательность целых чисел можно
>   записать и так: …,  0, 1547, 562, 35554,457,666,345,878,789. Из
>   определения целых чисел следует, что множество натуральных чисел
>   является подмножеством множества целых чисел. Поэтому, любое
>   натуральное число является целым, но не любое целое число является
>   натуральным.

Я пытался сделать так:

```
file1 = open('test.txt', 'r')
text1 = file1.read()

import re

even_num = []
new_t=[]
for int_numbers in range(0, len(re.findall(r"[0-9]+", text1))):
    if int(re.findall(r"[0-9]+", text1)[int_numbers]) % 2 == 0:
        even_num.append(re.findall(r"[0-9]+", text1)[int_numbers])
for iii in range(0,len(re.split(r"\s|\,", text1))-1):
    if re.split(r"\s|\,", text1)[iii] not in even_num:
        new_t.append(re.split(r"\s|\,", text1)[iii])
print(new_t)
```

В результате все четные числа удалились, но у меня возникли трудности с тем чтоб записать результат в тот же файл в том же формате.

Comment: Прочитать файл в массив, удалить из него все чётные числа, сохранить массив в файл. С какой из этих трёх подзадач у вас затруднения? Или сделать всё целиком за вас?

Comment: удалить все четные числа

Answer (score 1):

Рискну предположить, что числа в файле записаны построчно (на каждой строке одно число). Тогда так:

```
f = open('file.txt')
line = f.readline()
while line:
    try:
        if int(line) % 2 == 0:
            # это чётное число
            print(line)
        else:
            # это нечётное число
            pass
    except Exception:
        continue
f.close()
```

Далее можете делать с этими числами что угодно. Как вариант, собрать все нечётные в список и скинуть потом в файл.

Comment: Там текст в перемешку с цифрами, я пытаюсь через регулярные выражения, но попадаю в штангу...

Comment: @Валерий пример кода и пример данных в студию

Comment: Определение целых чисел утверждает, что любое из чисел 1, 2, 3, 4, число 0, а также любое из чисел 671, 256, 35  является целым. Теперь мы легко можем привести примеры целых чисел. Например, число 38 – целое, число 70040 – тоже целое, нуль – целое число (напомним, что нуль НЕ является натуральным числом, нуль – целое число), числа 999, 1, 8, 93, 832, – также являются примерами целых чисел.

Comment: @Валерий и..? далее?

Comment: file1 = open('test.txt', 'r')
text1=file1.readlines()

import re
patt=r"[0-9]+"
rrr=re.findall(patt, text1[0])#  все целые числа для первой строки

Comment: а далее я не знаю в какую сторону"копать"

Comment: я понимаю, что я мало что написал, просто подскажите как бы вы сделали, мне решение не нужно, я просто не могу сообразить